# Make For Loop Stop Counting Every 5 iterations C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, loops, for-loop

I'm using WinForms. In my forms I have a button. With every click of the button the program counts numbers. I'm using a for-loop to count the numbers between 1-500. How do i make my for loop stop every 5 counts?

My Code below counts to 5 then it stops. That is not what i want the loop to do. The loop should remember what number it left of previously then count from there, below is an example.

**For loop Couting Example:**  *Click*: 1 2 3 4 5 **(Stop)** *You click the button again*: 6 7 8 9 10 **(Stop)** *You click button again*: 11 12 13 14 15...etc

```
        for(int i = 0; i <= 500 ; i++)
        {
            Debug.Print("Value of i: " + i.ToString());               
            if(i == 5)
            {
                break;
            }                         
        }
```

Comment: What about continue?! instead of break

Comment: @CarbineCoder Then the `if` statement would be useless

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the current count in a member variable of your class and reinitialize the counter in the loop with that.

```
//In your class a private member:
private int masterCounter = 1;

//In your function  
for(int i = (masterCounter >= 500 ? 1 : masterCounter); i <= 500 ; i++)
{
    Debug.Print("Value of i: " + i.ToString());               
    if(i % 5 == 0)
    {
        masterCounter = i + 1;
        break;
    }                         
}
```

The code above resets to 1 once you have hit the 500 and click on the button again. So you can restart it at 500. The part with `(masterCounter >= 500 ? 1 : masterCounter)` does that as it returns 1 if `masterCounter` is greater or equal to 500 and otherwise it's current count which gets assigned as a starting value to `i`.

Another interesting part is `if(i % 5 == 0)` where it will evaluate as true only if i is a multiple of 5, because % calculates the remainder for integer divisions.

Comment: Every time i click on the button it says. The value of i: 0. That is not what i had in mind.

Comment: Where are you setting masterCounter? If you set it in the same method as the loop it will reset to 0 every time

Comment: It the private int masterCounter is above my button click event.

Comment: As @BlueBoy mentioned the line `private int masterCounter = 0;` has to go into the class as a member variable not inside the function. Otherwise it will get zeroed on each button click.

Comment: The `private int masterCounter` is not inside the function. It still gets zeroed.

Comment: My last edits should have fixed the issues. First we need to advance the count when we break out otherwise you get stuck on the same number indefinitely, and second since you count 0 based we have to shift the remainder calculation by 1. Now try again

Comment: There is one more issue. In the beginning i have to click on the button twice for it to start counting. Why is that?

Comment: 1st time i click on it the value is 0. 2nd time its works well. it says 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: Edited again so now everything is 1 based. instead of 0. Sorry I didn't read your description accurately that you want to start with 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert your variable as a private member

```
int i = 0;
```

then your code will be :

```
    for(; i <= 500 ; i++)
    {
        Debug.Print("Value of i: " + i.ToString());               
        if(i % 5 == 0)
        {
            break;
        }                         
    }
```

don't forget to add logics to 'reset' the variable i and I would recommend to use a better name

Answer (score 0):

You could use another variable:

```
private int num = 0; 
//Set this at the top of the class, not in the same function as the loop
```

Then use that to remember each time you click the button:

```
for(int i = num; i <= 500 ; i++)
{
    Debug.Print("Value of i: " + i.ToString());           
    if(i == num+5)
    {
        num+=5;
        break;
    }                         
}
```